# Is there a way to prevent an element in a vector to be destructed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I have a vector of some type, and I want to destruct the elements in some random order without moving the other elements in the vector.  At a later time I may inplace new in those destructed holes (or not).  When I destroy the vector, I don't want to call the destructor for an element that is already destructed, so is it possible to do so and if so how?

I've been thinking about using char[sizeof(T)] as the vector element type, but I see that std::align_of and std::aligned_storage are only suitable for POD storage.  So, how do I ensure that this will work for non POD types?

Is there some other way of doing this?

I'm working on MSVS2010 and may be upgrading soon to 2013.

Comment: *"I see that std::align_of and std::aligned_storage are only suitable for POD storage"* -- What makes you think that?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage, 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/aligned_storage/?kw=aligned_storage
and most importantly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983063%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: You are misunderstanding those references.  What it is saying is that `std::aligned_storage<T>::type` is POD.  But it can be used, via placement new, as storage for any type (of the appropriate size and alignment), POD or not.  Your first reference even states that, quite clearly: *"Provides the member typedef type, which is a POD type suitable for use as uninitialized storage for* **any** *object whose size is at most Len and whose alignment requirement is a divisor of Align"*

Comment: Oh, ok.  Post that as an answer and I'll give you cred.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how that answers your main question, though I've added a blurb about how to implement your own `optional`.

Answer (score 6):

```
std::vector<boost::optional<T>> v;
...
v[i] = boost::none; // destroy an object
```

If you can't use `boost`, then implementing your own `optional` class is fairly trivial.  Just use `std::aligned_storage<T>` along with a `bool` indicating whether the object is valid or not.

Comment: Although I'd like to use boost stuff, I'm too new to the project so would like to not add a hundred files to it quite yet. :)

Comment: +1 -- note though that using `std::vector<std::aligned_storage<T>::type>` isn't sufficient -- you do need to actually implement an optional type if you want to go there. (e.g. when vector calls `operator=` it won't be for `T` if you're using `aligned_storage` that way directly)

Comment: @BillyONeal: Yep, that's why I mentioned the `bool`.

Comment: Yep -- sorry, I was mentioning that to @Adrian . Didn't mean to say that as a comment on the answer.

Comment: @BillyONeal, not sure what you mean by *not being sufficient ... (e.g. when vector calls operator= it won't be for `T`*.  I do understand that I have to keep track of which ones are initialised so that I can destruct them, if that is what you are referring to.

Comment: I can't use aligned_storage since I may allocate any N elements which may change at runtime.  So I'll probably use alignment_of and just add elements on to that base number to generate an array.  Similar to what @Sinn was referring to.  But I'd be using move iterators so I don't have to do any explicit deletions.

Comment: @Adrian: How does that prevent you from using `aligned_storage`?  The `aligned_storage` object would be a member of the `optional` class, which you would need to create if you can't use `boost`.

Comment: aligned_storage gives out a type based on compile time constants.   I need runtime flexibility.

Comment: @Adrian: There's no compile time constraint here.  I'm not suggesting using one large `aligned_storage` buffer to store all your objects.  I'm suggesting multiple `aligned_storage` objects.  1 for each object you want to store.  They can be created dynamically, just like any other type.

Comment: That can be a huge waste of space since each element will contain additional padding of *(alignment - 1)*.  I.e. a 4 byte aligned element of size 4 will have each element be the size of 7 bytes.  Better to create an array of *(size*elements + alignment - 1)* bytes.

Comment: @Adrian: Yes, and doing that without destructors to help you while being exception safe is essentially impossible. When it comes to alignment, alignment means that the beginning of the type has to line up -- you can't cheat by only putting alignment on the end of the array. That will work on x86 (which is extremely forgiving of alignment faults) but nowhere else.

Comment: @BillyONeal, it is not essentially impossible, as the STL does do this for vector.  Also, IIRC, there is no padding beyond what the compiler states with sizeof().  I.e. if I have an array of types T, the address offset of element 1 from that of 0 is sizeof(T).  This would not be true with what Benjamin proposed.

Comment: @Adrian: `sizeof` is required to include the required padding. Also, the STL does not do this -- it has all of the behavior regarding ownership of that memory controlled by a type -- that type being `vector`. Trying to do that without using a type is essentially impossible. (Yes, it is possible, but it is terrible, and maintaining it will be certainly impossible)

Comment: @BillyONeal, I know that `sizeof` is required to include the required padding, that is why using an `aligned_storage<T>::type` object is overkill for all elements in an array.  You only need to align the first element and all elements following will be aligned, without having the excess padding introduced by `aligned_storage` being added to each element.  Further, what I meant by the STL doing this was specifically `vector` as you have mentioned.  `vector` doesn't allocate more padding then `sizeof` specifies for *each* element, though it would for the 1st to get everything else in line.

Comment: @Adrian: `aligned_storage` doesn't induce alignment padding costs for every element in the array. It basically creates a union with one member the size of the data you want, and one member with the alignment you want. The alignment the compiler does for that union does the "right thing" as far as arrays' padding is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can solve this by using a vector of shared_ptrs. When you want to get rid of an element, assign it to a nullptr shared_ptr.

Comment: No, I want to preserve locality.  Object pointed at by shared_ptr can be scattered around the system.

Answer (score -1):

Use an array?

```
Type * a = new Type[BASE_SIZE];
```

when inserting, if you need to extend use this

```
Type * tmp = new Type[BIGGER_SIZE];
std::copy(a, a + a.length, temp);
delete[] a;
a = tmp;
```

when delete just replace NULL or w/e, and replace it with a deletion mark, or w/e.

Comment: Are you mixing up Java and C++?

Comment: Lol sorry, currently on a Java project, didn't notice.

Comment: w/e?  What does that mean?  This still doesn't appear to help with the deletion of objects within the array.

Comment: @Adrian: It wasn't valid C++ before the edit.  But my comment wasn't only referring to the code, but the advice at the bottom.  He appears to be saying to set the objects to NULL, which is nonsense in C++, but makes sense in Java.

Comment: Oh, ic.  Still don't know what w/e means.

Comment: @Adrian: "w/e" means "whatever", I believe.

Comment: I thought of that, but I didn't quite understand what that meant in that context.

Comment: I meant a deletion mark,  value you undestand and use as "empty".